# Find triangle in the graph

Tags: haskell, graph

I have a graph like this:

[image: graph]

As part of a homework assignment I want to find the triangle `(1->2->5)`. I have no idea how to find this.

In my case, I defined my graph:

```
type Graph = (Int, Int -> Int -> Bool)

g 2 3 = True
g 3 2 = True
g 1 2 = True
g 2 1 = True
g 1 1 = True
g n m = False
```

### Answer to 2 comment.

I did this and it works, I think.

```
triangles :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
triangles = [(x, y, z) | x <- [1..3], y <- [1..x], z <- [1..y], isTriangle (x, y, z)]

isTriangle :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool
isTriangle  (x, y, z) = g x y && g y z && g x z
```

I removed `(_,g)` and `(n,g)` (I dont understand why we need them :)
I call `trinagles` and it return `(1,1,1) (2,1,1)` (in my case). Is it right?

Comment: Your correction is wrong, see my edited answer to know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the first Int of Graph is a bound for your nodes (like, 6 if the nodes are in `[1..6]`).

Therefore, you would like a function that returns the triangles of a graph, so the type might be:

```
triangles :: Graph -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
```

Now, a triangle exists whenever, for 3 nodes, say `x` `y` and `z`, all the combinations return `True` through `g`.

So, you might want to consider generating all these combinations (possibly avoiding the ones that are equivalent via re-ordering), and filter out only those that validate the criterion:

```
isTriangle :: Graph -> (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool
isTriangle (_, g) (x, y, z) == g x y && g y z && g x z
```

For this, you could use a [list comprehension](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension), or the function [filter](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afilter) which has type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`

---

Answer to your first comment:

First, you would need to implement the `triangles` function, which is the reason of the error. But, as you have done in `test`, you could simply generate these triangles on the fly.

Now, you wrote:

```
test = filter (isTriangle) [(x,y,z) | x <- [1..3], y <- [1..3], z <- [1..3]]
```

Two things about this:

- First, you wouldn't need the parentheses around `isTriangle` for what you wrote, but it is incorrect, since `isTriangle` expects a graph as its first parameter
- Second, you are going to obtain a lot of duplicates, and if you want, you can prevent this by not generating them in the first place:

  ```
  test = filter (isTriangle) [(x,y,z) | x <- [1..3], y <- [1..x], z <- [1..y]]
  ```

Alternatively, you can dismiss the `filter` function by providing a guard in the list comprehension syntax, as this:

```
[(x, y, z) | x <- [1..3],  y <- [1..x], z <- [1..y], isTriangle yourGraph (x, y, z)]
```

Now, I'll let you go on with the details. You will want to make this a function that takes a graph, and to replace this `3` by the number of nodes in the graph, and yourGraph by said graph.

Since you chose to use list comprehension, forget about the generating function that I wrote about earlier, its purpose was just to generate input for `filter`, but with the list comprehension approach you won't necessarily need it.

---

Answer to your second comment:

You want to write a function:

```
triangles :: Graph -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
triangles (n, g) = [(x, y, z) | ...]
```

The `...` are to be replaced with the correct things, from earlier (ranges for x, y and z, as well as the predicate isTriangle).

Alternatively, you can cut this in two functions:

```
allTriangles :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
allTriangles n = [(x, y, z) | ...]

graphTriangles :: Graph -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
graphTriangles (n, g) = [t | t <- allTriangles n, isGraphTriangle t]
    where isGraphTriangle (x, y, z) = ...
```

This way, you could potentially reuse `allTriangles` for something else. If you don't feel the need, you can stay with the one-shot big comprehension `triangles`, since it's a homework you probably won't build up on it.

I try not to fill all the `...` so that you can do it yourself and hopefully understand :)

---

Correcting your solution:

First, my mistake on the ranges, it should be `x <- [1..n], y <- [x+1..n], z <- [y+1..n]` where `n` denotes the number of nodes in your graph. This way, you only capture triples where `x < y < z`, which ensures that you only see one occurence of each set of three points.

Second, the reason why I put the graph as a parameter to the functions is that you might want to reuse the same function for another graph. By hardcoding `g` and `6` in your functions, you make them really specific to the particular graph you described, but if you want to compute `triangles` on a certain number of graphs, you do not want to write one function per graph!

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand how to connect `isTriangle` and `filter`. I tried this, but it doesn't work (of course). And in this string `isTriangle (_, g) (x, y, z) == g x y && g y z && g x z` console write `Parse error: naked expression at top level`  
`triangles :: Graph -> [(Int, Int, Int)]`  

`isTriangle :: Graph -> (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool`   
`isTriangle (_, g) (x, y, z) == g x y && g y z && g x z`   

`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`  
`test = filter (isTriangle) [(x,y,z) | x <- [1..3], y <- [1..3], z <- [1..3]]`

Comment: Ok. Last question. I don't understand what does mean `graph`. I see only a few functions wich show link betwen any of two vertex. What I should transmit in parameter?

Comment: Edited again. Try to think about what you want to achieve, and the types of the functions you need, and it should all fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t really like your graph type but whatever. Here’s the algorithm we will use:

1. First find a Node `x` of the graph.
2. For every other node `y` see if it connects to `x`
3. If `y` does connect to `x` then for each node `z`, see if it connects to `x` and `y`
4. If so then return it.

To avoid duplicates, we require `z<x<y`

```
nodes (n,_) = [1..n]
nodesBefore (n,_) k = [1..min n (k - 1)]
edge (_,e) x y = e x y
neighboursBefore g x = [ y | y <- nodesBefore g x, edge g x y]
triangles g = [(x,y,z) | x <- nodes g, y <- neighboursBefore g x, z <- neighboursBefore g y, edge g x z]
```